# How to find if OneDrive is active for a user in Office365 through API?

Tags: sharepoint, ms-office, office365, onedrive

Is there a way I could find out that a user has a OneDrive Site(for an Office365 account)?

I'm getting user list for my sharepoint site through

**https://{domain}-my.sharepoint.com/_api/web/siteusers**

but there is no field that could indicate if a user has an active OneDrive .By OneDrive I mean a personal site of this sort;

**https://{domain}-my.sharepoint.com/personal/user_name_domain_microsoft_com**

One way to find out is by accessing this URL for that user and check if it yields a  *404*  response.

I'm trying to get it done via the REST API? Any help on this?

Comment: Do you mean the user's OneDrive for Business or are you trying to discover if a O365 user has a personal OneDrive associated with that ID?

Comment: If an O365 user has a personal OneDrive... the Url is of this sort /personal/user_name_domain ... is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following User properties could be used to distinguish actual (or active) SPO users:

- [Principal.PrincipalType property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.principal.principaltype(v=office.15).aspx) - `PrincipalType.User`
  value specifies a **user** as the principal type
- [UserIdInfo.NameIdIssuer property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.useridinfo.nameidissuer(v=office.15).aspx) - configuration-agnostic
  reference to the type of the name identifier issuer, for SPO users its value: `urn:federation:microsoftonline`

REST request:

```
/_api/web/siteusers?$filter=PrincipalType eq 1 and UserId/NameIdIssuer  eq 'urn:federation:microsoftonline'
```

Comment: Thanks Vadim. Though it is the right way of finding that out but I have a rather unusual scenario. Even with this call you mentioned, I am still getting those users who either don't have OneDrive or are not part of the system/tenant anymore. 
I overcame this problem by taking intersection of users obtained through /siteusers call and the users obtained through Graph API.

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same problem.
@SyedMauzeRehan - Could you elaborate on the intersection you made? On what basis you managed to exclude those Users that are returned from '/_api/web/siteusers' but to not have an initialized personal drive?

Comment: You can now use the Unified Graph API for O365. If you find a Drive against a user, then you can say the user has a valid OneDrive.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this right now using the O365 Files REST API, but you can using Powershell cmdlets (e.g. this page http://blog.blksthl.com/2014/08/07/office-365-guide-series-provision-onedrive-for-business-using-powershell/ shows you how to use Powershell to provision OneDrive for Business for a list of users, from there it's just a slight modification to print out if these folks have OneDrive provisioned)

But another workaround, which you alluded to, is to use the O365 Files REST API and make a call to this endpoint:

https://your_SP_URL.com/_api/v1.0/me/drive

If you get an error, you'll know the Drive hasn't been provisioned yet. It's an ugly solution, but it should work just fine for your purpose.

Comment: Thank you! I was doing something similar.